# coldfusion builder rds fails dreamweaver cs4 rds works

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, dreamweaver, aptana

I am currently attempting use Adobe RDS built into Coldfusion Builder to connect to our servers RDS setup, no matter how I set it up to match Dreamweaver CS4 RDS it fails.

Everything through Dreamweaver RDS works fine, but I would rather use cf builder, any ideas or links?

Comment: I have no problem with CFBuilder to RDS.  Are u using CF9?  CFBuilder and CF8 don't work as well.

Comment: i have RDS working with CFBuilder with CF8 no problems.  Maybe you could post your settings and we could see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTTP connection over SSL/HTTPS?

If so it's possible that the SSL certificate you are using to connect isn't recognized by the JVM as a trusted ssl cert. In which case you would have to add your cert manually to the java keystore.

Comment: ty Pete for your reply.

currently it is not a https connection, would there be anything else that could be causing that in CF Builder?

Answer (score 0):

[Beta 2 of CFBuilder](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/coldfusionbuilder/) was released to the Labs on Monday - maybe give that a try and see if it solves the problem?

Comment: RDS works now with BETA2 however, its weird that it has trouble storing the password, so I have to enter it each time.  Also, it will not recognize the correct server path connecting from osx to a winbox.

Comment: Have you submitted these as bugs? (There'll be a form for that somewhere on labs.) Adobe can't fix stuff it doesn't know about.